# opensc-pkcs11 not getting any token

Tags: pkcs#11, opensc

I am writing a sample program using opensc-pkcs11.so in redhat linux. This is for pure software implementation of AES encryption/decryption. I am not using for any card.
My program intilizes the cryptoki successfully but giving CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT error. 
code snippet is given.

```
CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR pFunctionList; 
CK_C_Initialize pC_Initialize; 
CK_RV rv; 

rv = C_GetFunctionList(&pFunctionList); 
if(rv == CKR_OK)
pC_Initialize = pFunctionList -> C_Initialize; 

rv = (*pC_Initialize)(NULL_PTR);

    CK_ULONG ulSlotCount;
    CK_SLOT_ID_PTR pSlotList;

    CK_C_GetSlotList pC_GetSlotList;
    pC_GetSlotList = pFunctionList -> C_GetSlotList; 
    rv = (*pC_GetSlotList)(CK_FALSE, NULL_PTR, &ulSlotCount);

    /* Get list of all slots */
    //rv = C_GetSlotList(FALSE, NULL_PTR, &ulSlotCount);

    if (rv == CKR_OK) 
    {
        cout<<"ulSlotCount="<<ulSlotCount<<endl;
        pSlotList =
        (CK_SLOT_ID_PTR)
        malloc(ulSlotCount*sizeof(CK_SLOT_ID));
        //rv = C_GetSlotList(FALSE, pSlotList, &ulSlotCount);
        rv = (*pC_GetSlotList)(CK_FALSE, pSlotList, &ulSlotCount);
        if (rv == CKR_OK) 
        {
        /* Now use that list of all slots */
            l_lSlotId = pSlotList[0];
        cerr<<"lSlotId="<<l_lSlotId<<endl;


        }

        CK_SLOT_INFO slotInfo;
        CK_TOKEN_INFO tokenInfo;
        CK_C_GetSlotInfo pC_GetSlotInfo;
        pC_GetSlotInfo = pFunctionList -> C_GetSlotInfo;

        /* Get slot information for first slot */
        rv = (*pC_GetSlotInfo)(pSlotList[0], &slotInfo);
        fprintf(stderr, "pC_GetSlotInfo: rv = 0x%.8X\n", rv);
        if(rv == CKR_OK)
                   {
        /* Get token information for first slot */
            cerr<<"pC_GetSlotInfo OK"<<endl;

            CK_C_GetTokenInfo pC_GetTokenInfo;
            pC_GetTokenInfo = pFunctionList -> C_GetTokenInfo;
            rv = (*pC_GetTokenInfo)(pSlotList[0], &tokenInfo);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "pC_GetTokenInfo: rv = 0x%.8X\n", rv);
        if (rv == CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT) 
        {
            cerr<<"CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT"<<endl;
        }

        free(pSlotList);
    }
```

Can anybody give idea about what is happening? I believe opensc-pkcs11 can be used for just software implementation also.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKCS#11 library shipped with OpenSC acts "only as a driver" for a bunch of generally available [cryptographic smart cards](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-%28smart-cards-and-USB-tokens%29) so unless you have a physical card reader connected to your computer it won't find any slots. If you are looking for a pure software PKCS#11 implementation then I believe you should pick one from [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22685468/3325704). If none of them suits your need then maybe you could use some general purpose cryptographic library such as [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) or [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/).